# Does DRP mean dual-role-port or dual-role-power in typec

Tags: usb, usb-otg

I found drp mean dual-role-port in many blog, bug it mean dual-role-power in typec 2.0 Specification as below:
Dual-Role-Power (DRP) – for this mode, the port can behave either as a Source or
Sink.

is there changes in history

expect a closed official answer

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.